# Object not found with udipipe in R

Tags: r, nlp

I trying to use the udipipe package and getting and error in all the function of udipipe as object not found

Like
Error in upos %in% c("NOUN") : object 'upos' not found
Error in language %in% "english" : object 'language' not found

```
x=read.csv("Text.csv", header = T)

library(udpipe)
library(textrank)


comments <- subset(x, language %in% "english")
stats <- subset(x, upos %in% c("NOUN"))
```

Comment: I wonder if you mean "English" %in% language and c("NOUN" )%in% upos ?

Comment: Yes i meant the language and UPOS not found

Comment: I don't understand how your issue is related to the udpipe package. You should check `str(x)`. Apparently, there are issues with your data import as the data.frame doesn't contain columns you expect it to contain.